# seg fault when I change local class name

Tags: c++, class

segment fault is gone when I change the name of my class and I don't understand. I have built a class called `Environ` and I create it and call it in the main. What I have found is when I change the local variable name in main from `this_environ` to `environ` i get a segment fault where none of my Environ variables have been initialized. Has anyone come into this or understand why this would be an issue? The interesting thing is that this isn't an issue when I compile on my Ubuntu machine...

```
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
//#include "Environ.hpp"

// Namespaces
using namespace std;

class Environ {
    public:
    // Public objects.
    vector<unsigned> years_;

    void initialise() {
          cerr << "entering initialsie" << endl;
          years_ = {12,32,23};
    }
};

int main() {
    cout << "!!!Hello World!!!" << endl; // prints !!!Hello World!!!
    Environ this_environ;
    this_environ.initialise();
    cout << "Finished initialisation" << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

For reproducibility I am building on windows 10 with gcc version 5.1.0 with the following build call

```
g++ -std=c++0x -O2 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have just discovered that `environ` is a macro in stdlib so most likely not a good idea to call a variable this. The macro defined on line 633 of `stdlib.h`, perhaps I should mention my GCC is from [here](http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/download)

```
#define sys_errlist _sys_errlist
#define sys_nerr _sys_nerr
#define environ _environ
  char *__cdecl ecvt(double _Val,int _NumOfDigits,int *_PtDec,int *_PtSign) __MINGW_ATTRIB_DEPRECATED_MSVC2005;
  char *__cdecl fcvt(double _Val,int _NumOfDec,int *_PtDec,int *_PtSign) __MINGW_ATTRIB_DEPRECATED_MSVC2005;
  char *__cdecl gcvt(double _Val,int _NumOfDigits,char *_DstBuf) __MINGW_ATTRIB_DEPRECATED_MSVC2005;
  char *__cdecl itoa(int _Val,char *_DstBuf,int _Radix) __MINGW_ATTRIB_DEPRECATED_MSVC2005;
  char *__cdecl ltoa(long _Val,char *_DstBuf,int _Radix) __MINGW_ATTRIB_DEPRECATED_MSVC2005;
  int __cdecl putenv(const char *_EnvString) __MINGW_ATTRIB_DEPRECATED_MSVC2005;
```

Comment: Why not post the relevant information about `environ` being a macro in `stdlib`?  Give a link, post the quote saying "this is a macro", etc.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie could you explain a little more? what relevant information do you mean? I can not find an obvious link on where this macro is described. I only found this out be linking my IDE properly and then finding the macro in the source code.I am happy to help make this a better answer if you could give a little more guidance.

Comment: I don't quite understand how your code could have compiled, given that you claim that `environ` is a macro.  How could `Environ environ;
    environ.initialise();` compile, since `initialise()` is not a member function?  It just makes your answer more "suspicious" as to the real reason why your program didn't work.  That's where *you* need to fill in this gap that myself and probably others want filled.  Also `gcc` is open source -- you could post what this macro consists of.  I'm trying to make your answer up to par with what is expected on StackOverflow.

Comment: Indeed a mystery on compilation, lucky I have included a simple reproducible example.I have updated the answer to include the macro.